# Run Time Error During Merge Sort

Tags: c, merge, sorting, mergesort

i keep getting a runtime error every time i run this code, the algorithm seems to be right, i am using long values instead of integers because the array's size is large.

so what seems to be the problem?

```
void mergeSort(long left,long right, int a[],long n)
{

    clock_t ts,te;
    ts=clock();
    m2(left,right,a,n);
    te=clock();
    times[4]+=((double)(te-ts)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;

}

void m2(long left,long right, int a[],long n)//related to mergesort
{
    int center;
    if( left < right )
    {
        center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(left,center,a,n);
        mergeSort(center+1,right,a,n);
        merge(left,right,center,a,n);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Nathalie;

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "runtime error"? Where exactly is it occurring?

Comment: Just so you know, the C standard only guarantees 1 == sizeof (char) <= sizeof (short) <= sizeof (int) <= sizeof (long) <= sizeof (long long), and often a "long" is the same size as an "int"

Comment: @aix when i debug it a windows 7 message pops and says main.exe has stopped working

Comment: @Nathalie: This isn't possible to really debug right now.  For instance, we have no idea what times[4] is (is that array actually at least 5 in size?  If not, that's a problem).  You also haven't showed us the merge function.

Comment: can u post the code for merge? can u post the full code actually, during the program activation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Center is `int`, should be at least `long`.

In `m2`, you should recurse into `m2` and not `mergeSort` because you don't want to time the sub-calculations.

Possible cause for runtime error: stack overflow (pun :D) you are doing recursion and using O(n) space on the stack. Can't say anything else if you don't give us more information.